# Sorting using cosmosdb emulator not giving any results

Tags: azure-cosmosdb

I am trying to retrieve the latest value registered in the database for a proof of concept.

I use studio 3T to make things easier, and because i cannot connect via python (seperate issue).

my query looks like this:

```
{"Consumption": { $exists: true } }
```

This retrieves two documents, as i expect.
Now i want to sort the documents based on the timestamp ( an attribbute in consumption).
I added it like this (via drag and drop in studio 3T)

```
{"Consumption.Timestamp": 1}
```

But then i get no results on my query.

I have also tried using the ID of the document like this:

```
{"_id": 1}
```

This also produces no results

I can't seem to find any log or anything in the cosmosdb emulator.

Comment: Can you post what your document in the database looks like exactly?

Comment: **Cosmos DB is not MongoDB**. It is attempting to provide a MongoDB API lookalike, but it is a product from a different company. Thus the same query that works in MongoDB might not work at all or give an unexpected result in Cosmos DB.